# change resizer's properties thorguht css

Tags: css, html

i have a div which is resizeable through css.

**HTML** :

```
<div id="resize">
  <img src="{{env.assets_url}}assets/images/minified_signhere.png" [hidden]="!isNameNull(sign.name)" [attr.id]="'sign-img' + myindex">
  <img src="{{env.assets_url}}assets/images/minified_signhere_dim.png" [attr.id]="'dimimg' + myindex" [hidden]="isNameNull(sign.name)">
  <div style="position: absolute;z-index: 1000;left: 100%;" class="signbtns">
  <span style="font-size: 17px; margin-bottom: 5px" class="fa fa-trash float-right change-cursor" aria-hidden="true" (click)="deleteSign(myindex)"
  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click to delete the signature."></span>
  <span style="font-size: 17px;" class="fa fa-pencil float-right change-cursor" (click)="editSign(myindex)" aria-hidden="true"
  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click to edit the signature."></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and following is **CSS**

```
#resize {
  display: flex;
  resize: both;
  overflow:auto;
}
::-webkit-resizer {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: ew-resize;
}
```

div is being resize correctly. i want to customize the background color of resizer but the `::-webkit-resizer` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You change the color of `#resize`, not `::-webkit-resizer`.